# Add voltage and nominal current of a bulb with SIUNITX

Tags: siunitx, circuitikz

I want to display as the label of a bulb its nominal voltage and current.
I try :

```
\documentclass[border = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [vsource, l=$\SI{6}{V}$] (0,3) to[lamp, l=$\SI{6}{V},{100}{mA}$] (3,3) to [R, l=$R_1$] (3,0) -- (0,0);
```

but it causes me an error

how can I do ? thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3) to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{V}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3) to [R, l=$R_1$] (3,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the simplest solution is often the best

Comment: If you got versión 1.3.0 it should work also with `l={$\SI{6}{V}, \SI{100}{mA}$} `.